# Character plus number in C

Tags: c, char, output

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
char c1;
c1 ='A' +4;
printf("c1 = %c\n", c1);
}
```

and i get this output:

```
c1 = E
```

Can someone please explain it?

Comment: Look at an ASCII chart.

Comment: Try e.g. `printf("A = %d, E = %d\n", 'A', 'E');`

Comment: Another thing you can try is `'E' - 'A'`.

Comment: To understand the calculation it might help to be aware that the type of `'A'` is `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASCII value of English letter `A` is `65`, `B`'s `66` ... and `E`'s `69`.

The syntax:

```
c1 = 'A' + 4;
```

Gets converted into (since `printf()` uses `%c` specifier to represent `c1`):

```
c1 = 69; // 'A' holds 65 (implicitly converted into an integer before \
         //               performing assignment.)
```

And when it's again converted into `char`, it displays letter `E`.

Take a look at [ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com/) to get to know more about ASCII values.

Answer (score 0):

It works on ASCII values. You have assigned `A` in varibale `c1` and ASCII valie of A is 65. Than you have added 4 so it will become `65+4=69` now `printf` will look 69 belongs to which character 69 belongs to letter `E`

`ASCII values A-Z   65,66,   ... ,90`
      `values a-z   97,98 ,  ... ,122`

Answer (score 0):

In computers, everything is represented by numbers. Even each letter has its number. In the ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) encoding created by ANSI (American National Standards Institute), the values for each character are following:

[image]

In the `char` datatype, this are the numbers that are stored.

In C, character literals such as `'A'` are of type `int`. `'A'` would be 65 as you can see in the table.

Therefore if you do:

```
char c1;
c1 = 'A' + 4;
```

then

```
'A' + 4  equals  65 + 4  equals  69  equals  'E'
```

Then you supply it to printf with `%c` specifier, which prints it as a character instead of a number.